# How do I write a jQuery selector that will find elements that have string1 anywhere in its ID, and also string2 anywhere in its ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I write a jQuery selector that will find elements that have string1 anywhere in its ID, and also string2 anywhere in its ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean this? [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

> **Description**: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

example,

HTML

```
<input id="man-news" />
<input id="milkman" />
<input id="letterman2" />
<input id="newmilk" />
```

jQuery

```
$("input[id*='man']").val("has man in it!");
$("input[id*='man'][id*='letter']").val("has man and letter in it!");​
```

result: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xj24p/)

Comment: That's what I'm currently using, but I'm not sure how to use it to match two seperate strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain together the contains selector

```
$("span[id*='first'][id*='second']") // selector for any span with "first" and "second" anywhere in the id
```

Working example --> http://jsfiddle.net/mtgNE/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[id*=foo][id*=blah]');
```

would look for `foo` and `blah` at all available divs.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/XuKND/